# How To Find Out If An Admin Changed The Username On A User Record?

Tags: administration, user, user-management, user-record, admin

How do I find out if an Admin changed the username on a user record? There is no field history tracking for the User object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Lastmodifedby` field to identify Who attempt to change the username, but it's also not work when the user account receive more update on that day.

But there is an object called `Setup Audit Trail` in Salesforce. You can use that object to identify which user change the username for the specific user record. Please revise this [blog](https://blog.cloudanalogy.com/audit-trail-in-salesforce-how-to-setup-and-use-audit-trail/) to know more clear in that process.

You can retrive what are the changes by `Setup Audit Trail` will be explain on [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5).

Please let me know if it helps.